# SQL to fill missing value by AVG in each Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I want to fill missing date and Price with Average for below table

[image]

Sample data

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytable') is not null DROP TABLE #mytable
CREATE TABLE #mytable (CreateDate datetime, Product Varchar(4), Price money)
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES
('2023-06-09 17:01:00.000','Tree',1),
('2023-06-09 17:02:00.000','Tree',2),
('2023-06-09 17:03:00.000','Tree',3),
('2023-06-09 17:04:00.000','Tree',4),
('2023-06-09 17:01:00.000','BB',20),
('2023-06-09 17:02:00.000','BB',40),
('2023-06-09 17:04:00.000','BB',60),
('2023-06-09 17:01:00.000','Car',20),
('2023-06-09 17:03:00.000','Car',30),
('2023-06-09 17:04:00.000','Car',50)
```

Step 1 is to create a complete Datetime set

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateRange') is not null DROP TABLE #DateRange
Create Table #DateRange(CreateDate datetime Primary key Clustered)
GO

Declare @startdate datetime = '2023-06-09 17:01:00', @endtime datetime = '2023-06-09 17:04:00'
While (@startdate <= @endtime)
BEGIN
Insert into #DateRange values (@startdate)
set @startdate = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, @startdate)
END
```

Step 2 to fill NULL with average of **Only ONE upper** and **Only ONE** **lower number**  , not AVG of all rows

```
SELECT d.CreateDate,
COALESCE(Price, AVG(Price) OVER ()) as New_Price,
m.*
From #DateRange d
LEFT OUTER JOIN #mytable m on d.CreateDate = m.CreateDate
and Product = 'BB'
```

My question is how loop through **each Product Group** so I don't need to set product = BB explicitly?

My expected result is

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE.
First create list date and create list unique Product

Then join List Date_uniqueProduct with table mytable for find gap with date

```
Declare @startdate datetime = (select  min(CreateDate) from #mytable)
, @endtime datetime =(select  max(CreateDate) from #mytable)


;with Listunique as (
select   distinct Product
from #mytable
),

_List (date_,Product) as ( 
        select @startdate as date_,Product
        from (select distinct Product from  Listunique)a
        union all
        select  DATEADD(minute,1, date_) as date_,Product
        from _List
        where date_ <@endtime

)
select a.*,f.price
from _List a

full join #mytable b on a.date_=b.CreateDate and a.Product=b.Product
outer apply (
                select sum(ISNULL(p,0) +ISNULL(n,0)) /2 as price
                from (
                        select  Price as p,0 as n from #mytable l 
                        where l.Product=a.Product and l.CreateDate=DATEADD(minute,-1, a.date_)
                        union 
                        select 0 as p,Price as n from #mytable l 
                        where l.Product=a.Product and l.CreateDate=DATEADD(minute,1, a.date_)
                )d
            )f
where b.CreateDate is null
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/knmJZsCw)

Comment: @abolfazi you missing the AVG price of Only ONE upper and Only ONE lower number

Comment: @PyBoss, I edited my code and add Price

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (if you are using SQL Server 2022):

```
declare @start_time datetime = '2023-06-09 17:01:00';
declare @end_time datetime = '2023-06-09 17:04:00';

with Calendar as 
(-- step1: build a calender table based on your start and end time.
  select top(datediff(minute, @start_time, @end_time) +1)
         dateadd(minute, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @start_time) dt
  from master..spt_values
)
select all_dts.dt as CreateDate,
       p.product,
       -- use first_value and last_value functions with the (ignore nulls) option to get the next and previous not null price value.
       isnull(tbl.price, 
              (isnull(first_value(tbl.price) ignore nulls over (partition by p.product order by all_dts.dt range between current row and unbounded following), 0) +
              isnull(last_value(tbl.price) ignore nulls over (partition by p.product order by all_dts.dt range between unbounded preceding and current row), 0)) /2.0
            ) as price 
from Calendar all_dts
-- step2: do a cross join between the generated dates in step1 and the distinct values of products to get all possisble combinations of (dates and products)
cross join (select distinct product from #mytable) p
-- step3: do a left join with the table to get the missing dates
left join #mytable tbl
on all_dts.dt = tbl.CreateDate and
   p.product = tbl.product
order by p.product, all_dts.dt
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cFeDLKwc)

For previous versions of the SQL server, we could implement a subquery instead of the `first_value` and `last_value` functions with the `ignore null`:

```
declare @start_time datetime = '2023-06-09 17:01:00';
declare @end_time datetime = '2023-06-09 17:04:00';

with Calendar as 
(-- step1: build a calender table based on your start and end time.
  select top(datediff(minute, @start_time, @end_time) +1)
         dateadd(minute, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @start_time) dt
  from master..spt_values
)
select all_dts.dt as CreateDate,
       p.product,
       -- Use subquery to get the next and previous not null price value.
       isnull(tbl.price, 
              (isnull((select top 1 price from #mytable mtbl where mtbl.product = p.product and mtbl.CreateDate > all_dts.dt order by CreateDate), 0) +
               isnull((select top 1 price from #mytable mtbl where mtbl.product = p.product and mtbl.CreateDate < all_dts.dt order by CreateDate desc), 0)) /2.0
            ) as price 
from Calendar all_dts
-- step2: do a cross join between the generated dates in step1 and the distinct values of products to get all possisble combinations of (dates and products)
cross join (select distinct product from #mytable) p
-- step3: do a left join with the table to get the missing dates
left join #mytable tbl
on all_dts.dt = tbl.CreateDate and
   p.product = tbl.product
order by p.product, all_dts.dt
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/durj1h9f)

Comment: If you want only the missing rows, you could wrap the query in another CTE and select only rows `where tbl.product is null` [(explained in the demo)](https://dbfiddle.uk/t-aDBt6E)

Comment: what should i replace master..spt_values

Comment: You still could use `master..spt_values`. And there are many ways you could build your own numbers table, it could be just a table containing one column and a specific amount of rows.

Comment: For example, you could try this way https://dbfiddle.uk/9dCjdaYt and use it this way https://dbfiddle.uk/eZhRXkgq

Comment: for the AVG price, I want to calculate the average of Only ONE upper and Only ONE lower number, not the entire rows AVG

Comment: Well, in this case, for BB it would be (40 + 60) /2 = 50, not 30, right? And if the previous or next price is null what value should be picked for the avg? i.e. when two or more consecutive dates are missing.

Comment: my bad, the AVG should be 50, I fixed it, and if the previous price is NULL too, then look for the previous 2 price, if 2 is NULL, repeat it find a number

Comment: You may check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GENERATE_SERIES` to create a date range, join this list of dates to the table to identify the missing values, and then fill in the missing values using the average of only the first and last record of each group using (`FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`):

```
Declare @startdate datetime = (select min(CreateDate) from #mytable)
,@endtime datetime =(select max(CreateDate) from #mytable);

with daterange as (
  SELECT DATEADD(minute,value,@startdate) as CreateDate, Product
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(datepart(minute, @startdate) - 1, 
                     datepart(minute, @endtime) - 1,1)
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Product FROM #mytable) p
),
cte as (
  SELECT d.*, t.Price
  FROM daterange d
  LEFT JOIN #mytable t on d.CreateDate = t.CreateDate AND d.Product = t.Product
),
avg_cte as (
  select *,(COALESCE(first_value(price) ignore nulls over (partition by product order by CreateDate range between current row and unbounded following), 0) +
           COALESCE(last_value(price) ignore nulls over (partition by product order by CreateDate range between unbounded preceding and current row), 0)) /2.0 as avg_price
  from cte
)
select CreateDate, Product, avg_price
from avg_cte
where price is null
```

Result :

```
CreateDate              Product Price
2023-06-09 17:03:00.000 BB      50.0000
2023-06-09 17:02:00.000 Car     25.0000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1DofLYGx)

Comment: the math is wrong,  fill NULL with average of upper and lower number, you take AVG of all rows